# QProgressBar busy not working

Tags: qt, c++11

I am trying to create a `QProgressBar` to indicate the execution of an action of which I don't know the time it will take to complete before execution.

Right now I have the following

```
QProgressBar DLbar;
DLbar.setMaximum(0);
DLbar.setMinimum(0);
DLbar.show();
```

I have set the minimum and maximum both to `0`, which should result in a busy indicator based on the [Qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qprogressbar.html#details):

> If minimum and maximum both are set to 0, the bar shows a busy
>   indicator instead of a percentage of steps. This is useful, for
>   example, when using QNetworkAccessManager to download items when they
>   are unable to determine the size of the item being downloaded.

When I run the program the progress bar is shown but instead of having the busy indicator it's full and stays like that until the operation finishes.

I tried setting the `DLbar` parent to be the main window but there's the same problem.

Example:

```
QProgressBar DLbar;
DLbar.setMaximum(0);
DLbar.setMinimum(0);
DLbar.show();
for( int i=0; i<1000000; i++ )
    qDebug() << i;
```

Comment: Do you perform long-time operation in GUI thread? If so, start it from another thread and try again.

Comment: Can't repro (Linux, Qt5.8).  Please edit your question to include a [mcve].

Comment: @G.M. edited, with this example the bar shows but it's full and doesn't move until the loop ends (OS X Yosemite, Qt5.7)

Comment: You're blocking the event loop.  That's not how `Qt` works.  Once you've created the progress bar and set its parameters you need to return to the event processing loop.

Comment: @G.M. how can i do that? I know how to use a QDialogBar and have it fill up by calling ```setvalue``` but i can't figure a way to do it while having a busy indicator

Comment: Why do you have the min and max both 0?

Comment: @drescherjm in the documentation it says that having both min and max set to 0 will show a busy indicator which is what i wanted to do

Comment: I believe the only way you can get this to work is put your work in a different thread than the GUI thread. The GUI needs to be responsive for this to work. You can call Process events in your work loop (when it is in the same thread as the GUI) but you will have to call it often.

Answer (score 2):

The basic problem is that you're not allowing the `Qt` event loop to process events.  A minimal example to demonstrate would be something like...

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <QApplication>
#include <QProgressBar>

int
main (int argc, char **argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  QProgressBar DLbar;
  DLbar.setMaximum(0);
  DLbar.setMinimum(0);
  DLbar.show();

  /*
   * The following sleep will prevent any events being processed for 10s...
   */
  std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(10));

  /*
   * ...after which we start the event loop and everything should start working.
   */
  exit(app.exec());
}
```

If you're going to be using `Qt` you really need to get a firm understanding of the underlying [event system](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/eventsandfilters.html).

**Edit 1:**  You ask...

> i still don't understand why it's not working even if i use
>   QCoreApplication::processEvents() inside the loop.

It will work if, in the example above, you replace...

```
exit(app.exec());
```

with...

```
while (true)
  QCoreApplication::processEvents();
```

Comment: ok i get that but i still don't understand why it's not working even if i use ```QCoreApplication::processEvents()``` inside the loop. Shouldn't that make the bar move?

Comment: I just tried your code and it still doesn't work, i only see a full progress bar that doesn't move

Comment: "i only see a full progress bar that doesn't move".  For how long?  Try removing the call to `std::this_thread::sleep_for`.

Comment: It always stays still, been waiting 2 minutes now. Removing the call to sleep changes nothing with both the while loop and exit

Comment: Which platform and `Qt` version (I'm Linux and Qt5.8)?

Comment: OS X Yosemite Qt5.7

Comment: setting the app style to ```"window"``` the bar does what it's supposed to do so i guess it's a bug in the ```"macintosh"``` style